# Android rating bar scrambled view

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have been trying to fix this for a long time now but couldn't find any thing useful.

I have a simple xml layout file which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_with_shadow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/list_image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewAppIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAppName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/llThumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/llThumbnail"
        android:text="App Name Here"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llThumbnail"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:rating="4" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the rating bar looks perfectly well as expected on 1 device but it looks completely scrambled on other (HTC One, Android version: 4.2.2).
The above xml is (a row) shown inside a listView.

Here is a snapshot:

[image]